# How do I find out if a watir object's browser is closed or not? (after typing ctrl+C or otherwise)

Tags: watir

When I close the browser watir has been using (or hit ctrl+C and close it out that way), I get these types of errors...

```
b = Watir::Browser.new
#ctrl+C and closes browser window
b.url
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)
```

...when I run something like #url or #goto on the watir object.

I tried methods like #closed? and #closed on the object, but they aren't recognized. Have also tried this:

```
b.methods - Object.methods
```

and perused the available methods but nothing has worked so far.

Short of responding to raised error messages with begin/rescue blocks, what methods can I use to determine if the browser window is closed?

A bonus would be a method that would allow me to reinitialize the browser window, keeping any preferences picked up along the way. That would be the best possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use exists? method to check whether browser is closed or not, browser.exists? would true if browser is open, If not, it would return false.

Comment: This works after closing the browser window via UI interaction, but if you close the browser window perhaps even inadvertently by typing "ctrl+C", it throws the `Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused...` error

Answer (score 0):

Going to answer my own question here because I'm not sure if a straightforward answer is possible. Monkey-patching time.

```
class Watir::Browser
  def try(meth)
    begin
      self.send(meth.to_sym)
      true
    rescue
      false
    end
   end

   def open?
     if try(:exists?)
       exists?
     else
       false
     end
   end

end
```

Works no manner which way you closed your browser window.

I may submit a pull request

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this? ctrl-c is a manual execution. It ends the session. There is no reason to then make any calls to the driver because the session is over. This will never happen during the course of a test execution.

Comment: Discovery of the properties of an object, session over or not. Doesn't matter

Comment: Right, what properties? I'm trying to understand any use case where you can get useful information without a session. (and I'm not just asking, I'm the one who would approve or reject your PR).

Comment: You have a browser object, you want to determine if it still represents an open browser window. You check it out, it crashes your script. You'd rather check that out without it actually raising an error. I just don't like using begin/rescue blocks unnecessarily

Comment: Either 1) This is happening manually (because ctrl-c is manual), or 2) The browser itself is crashing somehow, so how would you know when to call open? This is only if you are messing around with the browser to create a test in the first place? What difference does it make if it throws an exception or returns false if you are making a manual call?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to close the browser is `browser.quit` or `browser.close`
Then you can call `browser.exists?` and it will return `false`. Sending `ctrl+C` exits your session entirely, so there is no longer anything listening at the url/port you are making calls to, and you will always get that error.

Comment: Yeah, but in practice watir hangs a lot on certain elements and pages and ctrl+C can happen a lot when you're trailblazing through a new environment trying to build a script. Like those times when you've automated the first part of your test (sign in, etc), but you want to get that browser object back so you can continue to work on the script.

Comment: Do you just want to keep the browser open after you do a ctrl-c?